# Can Cplex generate a set from the resulted variables (i.e. not initialization)?

Tags: optimization, mathematical-optimization, cplex, opl

I am currently planning a load optimization model. My desired result is 6 routes with more or less the same load assigned to them. However, i also want to impose a constraint that restricts the time spent on each route to below a certain amount.

The variable of interest is `X[i][j][k]` which is a boolean value, with i being the starting location, j the destination location, k the route number. For example, `X[2][4][1]=1` means that the Route number 1 visits location 2 and then 4.

I only have this concept in my mind that somehow, using Cplex, we can create a set that keeps track of all the locations that cannot be assigned to a route because that route has exceeded the target time. Is such a function available on Cplex? Or how could I change my formulation to get that result? I want to use that set to assign another separate route that deals with those locations left

Comment: The description is a bit fuzzy, but i would go as far as: 1) No, there is no such convenience funtion. What you ask for might be a (more) common thing in (advanced) CP solvers (*accumulations*) due to them being focused on domain-pruning and supporting reification concepts, but if you are using cplex, you are using math-opt. 2) You might want to have a look into *travelling salesman problem with time windows* formulations as those basically need the same reasoning for working correctly (and you seem to have the assignment-polytope concept already: bool-vars = edges). Those are somewhat tricky

Comment: @sascha thank you, i sort of figured out it wouldn't be possible. I'll try to simplify the problem some more